# How to safely used a padded struct as a hashmap key

Tags: c, libuv

I'm using `libuv` to write a UDP server. To tell clients apart I need to look at the source IP and source port. This is provided in the `on_read` callback as `const struct sockaddr*`. I need to use this information as the key for looking up the user's context somehow.

Ideally I would use a hashmap and use this struct as the key. However it's not clear if `libuv` zero initialises that structure and so there could be random data in the padding making it unsuitable as a raw hashmap key (a `memcmp` on the struct).

Assuming that `libuv` doesn't zero out the padding first, what would be the most efficient way to build a key out of this information?  I am thinking I can simply use assignment or `memcpy` to copy the two fields I want into a clean struct, but I would have to do this for every packet.

I know that in the grand scheme of things this is not a huge amount of overhead, but have I missed a more elegant or efficient solution?

Edit: I've updated the title to reflect that even though my challenge is with `libuv` right now, this isn't really just a libuv specific problem as a struct like this could come from a number of places. When you get passed a struct from somewhere and you need to use that (or its contents) as a key, what's the correct / safe way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Adding "generic" response, moving back the bad libuv TCP response.

If you don't want to copy the struct (that is very small in this case, but as a generic problem) the straightforward solution is hash member by member.

Let's assume that you need to extract a lot of sparse fields from a large struct. For example, if the hash is only to sum:

```
#define KEY_INITIAL_STATUS 0

void hash(char *status, const char *buf, size_t len) {
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i<len; ++i)
        status += buf[i];
}

void receive_buf(struct addr_t addr, ...) {
    char key = KEY_INITIAL_STATUS;
    hash(&key, addr.field1, addr.field1_len);
    hash(&key, addr.field2, addr.field2_len);

    void *value = hashtable_search(hashtable, key, ...);

    // Do things with the value
}
```

The majority of hashes can be calculated this way, and then optimized (no need to be byte by byte).

Benchmark is needed to check if is better to do this or to copy all to a zeroed struct.

---

I see that the libuv read callback use this signature:

`void read_cb(uv_stream_t * stream, ssize_t nread, const uv_buf_t *buf)`

The client data is linked to the connection/stream, and libuv already have done this lookup for you. The library expects you to pass the data somehow.

If I look for the doc here:

http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/stream.html

> "See also: The `uv_handle_t` members also apply."

So if I check the `uv_handle_t` members in http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/handle.html#c.uv_handle_t:

> void* uv_handle_t.data
>
> Space for user-defined arbitrary data. libuv does not use this field.

So you should save and use your client information here, no need for you to do a single search.

In other libraries, is common to return this type of data either in the connection struct, as a parameter in the "on_read" (or similar) callback as a `void *` pointer , or even allocating more memory in the `library_stream_t` structure, like `malloc(sizeof(uv_stream_t) + sizeof(my_opaque_data)`.

Comment: thanks for the answer! But this is for stream based connections. UDP based connections don't have a "per connection" state as one socket receives packets for all users. I would love to be wrong on this though! :)

Comment: Ouch! Sorry, I completely missed that part! I think that the safe bet should be to cast structure to `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6` and use the data there for key building.

Comment: The problem with that though is `sockaddr_in` has a lot of padding bytes. Unless those are zero'd out by `libuv`, then they could be different each time, which means the key would be different and wouldn't find the entry in the hash. I can't control what `libuv` does, so I'm trying to figure out what the safest way to do this is, assuming padding isn't zero'd.

Comment: Then it highly depend on the domain problem. You can use SO_REUSEADDR/REUSEPORT to create many sockets and reduce hashtable entries. On other solution, you can bind a new port for each client and instruct the client to connect to that other port (can cause problems with firewalls or if the volume is very high). Or do not allow more than one client per ip address, so you only need to hash ip address and not port...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend directly using the `struct` as a key, but rather choose a `Set` or `Hashtable` library that allows you to pass in a comparator, when you initialize it. Of course the comparator should know how to compare the `struct`.